# booktype installation on cent os 6.7

Tags: python, postgresql, centos, booktype

I tried to install `booktype` with `postgresql` on `cent os 6.7` but not able to finish as i am getting stuck on errors.
i had referred the below link for installation:

http://sourcefabric.booktype.pro/booktype-20-for-authors-and-publishers/installation-on-gnulinux/

but while I entered the below command:

```
./createbooktype -p prod --check-versions --database postgresql /var/www/booktype/instance1
```

it shows the error that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./createbooktype", line 22, in <module>
    import argparse
ImportError: No module named argparse
```

kindly help me to get over this. i am using python 2.7 as default.

Comment: Does `python -c 'import argparse'` work?

Comment: ya its worked when i tried from                                                [root@vps233474 ~] but when i am standing at (mybooktype)[root@vps233474 mybooktype]# the version showing is python 2.6.6 and the above command shows the error that:    Traceback (most recent call last): File "./createbooktype", line 22, in import argparse ImportError: No module named argparse

Comment: `argparse` was introduced in Python 2.7, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse. Therefore `createbooktype` unfortunately will not run with 2.6.6. I suggest that you upgrade to Python 2.7 if possible.

Comment: i had upgraded and when i am at [root@vps233474~] shows the version python2.7  but when i started booktype commands and if i am at (mybooktype)[root@vps233474 mybooktype]#  it showing the python version as 2.6.6. why its like that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) was introduced in Python 2.7 so the `createbooktype` command will fail when run with older Python versions.

You are using virtualenv, no? It looks like the virtualenv for your booktype installation uses Python 2.6.6.

Now that you have upgraded your system to 2.7 you can create a new virtualenv for Python 2.7. Use the `--python=python2.7` option to `virtualenv`, although since upgrading that is probably the default version now.

Then activate your new virtualenv and install booktype.

Comment: i had successfully created the new virtualenv and the rest of steps had completed. but when i entered the below command:   django-admin.py syncdb --noinput
it shows the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/mybooktype/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line() ................................................................ etc.... and finally....
      "settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.

Comment: the same error for the below 3 commands:  django-admin.py syncdb --noinput
                                                                                                                               django-admin.py migrate
                                                                            django-admin.py createsuperuser

Comment: Can u reply me asap. I am waiting to get updates from you

Comment: Isn't the command `./manage.py syncdb`? Anyway, as the error message says, the database is not properly configured. Edit your `base.py` file and configure the database as per the instructions in the link that you show in your question.